# Remove matches in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

What I am trying to do is, convert `html` select option to part of `mysql` query, first get all options text to an array then into a string, but want to prevent include some options in this string in foreach loop.

What I tried so far, but it include all options, I used

```
if (v != 'blah 0' || v != 'blah 99' || v != 'blah 100') {
```

but not working. I don't want to put these values in string.

```js
var array = [];
var str = "";
$('select option').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  array.push(text);
});
$.each(array, function(i, v) {
  if (v != 'blah 0' || v != 'blah 99' || v != 'blah 100') {
    str += '("' + v + '" ,18),';
  }
});

console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>blah 1</option>
  <option>blah 0</option>
  <option>blah 2</option>
  <option>blah 3</option>
  <option>blah 4</option>
  <option>blah 0</option>
  <option>blah 5</option>
  <option>blah 99</option>
  <option>blah 100</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should use `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: Why would you ever need to create a mysql query in the browser? Sounds like a terrible security hole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use and `&&` instead of or `||` in condition

```js
var array = [];
var str = "";
$('select option').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  array.push(text);
});
$.each(array, function(i, v) {
  if (v != 'blah 0' && v != 'blah 99' && v != 'blah 100') {
    str += '("' + v + '" ,18),';
  }
});
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>blah 1</option>
  <option>blah 0</option>
  <option>blah 2</option>
  <option>blah 3</option>
  <option>blah 4</option>
  <option>blah 0</option>
  <option>blah 5</option>
  <option>blah 99</option>
  <option>blah 100</option>
</select>
```

Also you can use `.filter()` and `.map()` instead

```js
var str = $('select option').filter(function() {
  return ['blah 0', 'blah 99', 'blah 100'].indexOf($(this).text()) == -1;
}).map(function(){
  return '("'+$(this).text()+'" ,18)';
}).toArray().join(',');

console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>blah 1</option>
  <option>blah 0</option>
  <option>blah 2</option>
  <option>blah 3</option>
  <option>blah 4</option>
  <option>blah 0</option>
  <option>blah 5</option>
  <option>blah 99</option>
  <option>blah 100</option>
</select>
```